# What is the difference between SweetAlert and JS prompt box

Tags: javascript, sweetalert, sweetalert2

*in simple javascript code the input of the  prompt box work properly*

```
f = prompt ("write a number here") 
   r = 1;
   x = f-r;
   alert(x);
```

**when style the prompt box with sweetalert  the result will be NaN  before you write the input value**

```
  f = swal({
  title: "An input!",
  text: "Write something interesting:",
  type: "input",
  showCancelButton: true,
  closeOnConfirm: false,
  animation: "slide-from-top",
  inputPlaceholder: "Write something"
},
function(inputValue){
  if (inputValue === false) return false;

  if (inputValue === "") {
    swal.showInputError("You need to write something!");
    return false
  }

  swal("Nice!", "You wrote: " + inputValue, "success");
});

   r = 1;
   x = f-r;
   alert(x);
```

Comment: Of course it is, thanks - didn't read properly... @AlonEitan

Comment: OP: Please note that although that duplicate is about AJAX async request, it's still very much related - You need to put that code in the second example **inside** the callback function (Where you validate the `inputValue` parameter), because it's available only after the user click on the "OK" button. Unlike `prompt` that stops the code from execute until the the user enter a value, swatalert will allow the code to run in the background

Comment: @AlonEitan when i did that it it be available only after the user click on the "OK" button , but the return still allways NaN

Comment: @SlimSoussia Put that code right after `swal("Nice!", "You wrote: " + inputValue, "success");` and before (`});`), something like `r = 1;f=parseInt(inputValue); x = f-r;alert(x);`

Comment: @AlonEitan thank you this solved the probleme , inputvalue wasn't int its value was an object ?

Comment: @SlimSoussia No, it's `<input type="text">` the input you see on sweetalert, so it return a **string** - `"8"` instead of `8` (for example)